# How do I take screenshot of a minimized Window?

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot, screen-capture

I'm building a small video recording of a specific Windows but I just noticied it will not work when the Window is minimized, it take screenshot only the application's window superior bar. Is possible to workaround it?

Here's my current code:

```
public Bitmap GetScreenshot(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            RECT rc;

            if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (var gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
                bool succeeded = PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
                gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
                if (!succeeded)
                {
                    gfxBmp.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
                }
                IntPtr hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
                GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hRgn);
                Region region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);
                if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))
                {
                    gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);
                    gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                }
                return bmp;
            }
        }
```